# When/how is 1.5X/2.0X speedup playback available in YouTube with HTML5 browser enabled?

Tags: youtube, video

In the past I have seen 1.5X/2.0X playback in YouTube working on some YouTube videos.

To ensure this was not due to "old" YouTube videos, I chose a random 2014 Superbowl commercial. I cannot see any speedup playback controls.

https://www.youtube.com/user/mmschocolate?v=q3Z4TQKGXbE

I am using Chrome on OS X Mavericks.

[image]

**Update**  After a half dozen attempts the speed setting is *now showing up* - *on the same video it did previously.*

I have no clue what has caused the speedup capability to reappear: I did not make any Settings changes in the interim.

[image]

Comment: is it possible that it was temporarily disabled on youtube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google youtube html5 - this will take you to a page that allows you to select html5 as the preferred player.  HTML 5 = player - you have the speed option.  Flash = player - no speed option.